# Siding Installation - Rain Expected

Tags: siding

I am having my entire house re-sided. We are having vinyl clapboard installed over the existing asbestos shingles. Some of the house is completed but an entire side is currently covered in Polar Wrap insulation (Tyvek below). Tomorrow there is 100% chance of rain. What happens when the Polar Wrap gets soaked? Does it need to be removed and re-installed? Or do we have to wait until it dries to finish applying vinyl? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The surface of Polar Wrap, according the the manufacturer, is impervious to weather, it will not be an issue for your vinyl siding. If there are any voids, nail holes present, a small bit of water will pass through penetrations and can get trapped, taking a while to evaporate. This may not be an issue either, but if you choose, you can temporarily block the entry of rain by running a line of duct tape or other wide tape to divert the rain over the siding rather than letting it run behind the siding.

I do believe the existing siding will still protect the structure from what little water may get through still.